# Finding coefficients in polynomial efficiently

Tags: polynomials, gap

Given a transitive $G$-set $ M $. I'm interested in finding the number of fixed points of $ G $ acting on $\operatorname{Pot}_a( M ) := \left\{ N\subseteq M; |N| = a \right\} $ by using the table of marks of $G$. Let $U_1, \dots, U_s $ be representatives of the conjugacy classes of subgroups of $ G $. For each of them, a polynomial

$$p_{U_i} := \prod_{l=1}^s \left( \sum_{j=0}^{m_{i,l}} \binom{m_{i,l}}{j}\cdot x^{\lambda(i,l)\cdot j} \right)$$

is defined, where $\lambda(i,l), m_{i,l}\in \mathbb N_0$. Let $ p := \sum_{i=1}^s p_i $. The coefficient of $x^p$ is the number of fixed points $G$ has on $\operatorname{Pot}_p( M ) $. The problem is to calculate these coefficients efficiently. My approach was to calculate

$$p_{U_i} := \prod_{l=1}^s \left( \sum_{j=0}^{m_{i,l}} \binom{m_{i,l}}{j}\cdot x^{\lambda(i,l)\cdot j} \operatorname{mod}x^{p+1} \right) \operatorname{ mod } x^{p+1}.$$

Each transitive $G$-set corresponds to a row in the table of marks of $G$ since $M\cong G/U_k$ for some $U_k \leq G$. It turns out that calculating the fixedpoints of $S_8$ on $\operatorname{Pot}_2( G/U_p )$ for $p=2 \dots 148$ takes more than 10 hours ( still not finished ) which is not acceptable. 
To define the polynomial I used the internal GAP functions Product, Sum and mod. Do you have any suggestions how I can calculate the coefficients faster?

Comment: The calculation took about 22 hours. The main problem for GAP is to calculate the $p_{U_i}$. It takes very long do define this polynomial for GAP.

Comment: For the inner sum, you may use `PolynomialByExtRep` or even PolynomialByExtRepNC if you trust the arguments, see [here](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap66.html). Then at least you don't have to use `Sum` and inner `mod`. I'm not sure how much speedup you'll gain though, since I expect that it's multiplication which takes most of the time, but this would be a worthwhile optimisation anyhow. Looking forward to hear if this will have any effect, then let's see further.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Thank you very much, this was really helpful! For the small examples it takes about 30% less time then before, the big examples are still running. I had to change quit a bit of the code, e.g. replace mod by QuotRemLaurpols and add some if loops. But you're right, most of the time is used for calculating the product. Do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Well, it turns out the effect on bigger groups is much better! The calculation that took 22 hours before is now finished in 59 mins. Thanks, I'm really grateful. Nevertheless I would be interested in any additional tips you can give me.

Comment: Great! For further tips, for this hour-long calculation it's interesting to know what is $s$ (the number of polynomials to multiply) and what are their degrees? Are these polynomials  dense or sparse? If sparse, how many monomials do they have? Finally, are you interested to know only one coefficient for $x^p$ for a fixed $p$ at a time, if that could be faster, or you want to calculate the whole polynomial anyway?

Comment: Had some more thoughts - perhaps this could be improved further by using the functionality described in [Arithmetic for External Representations of Polynomials](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap66.html#X809028CD7C0EA7CE) or even [Vectors as coefficients of polynomials](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap23.html#X87FEC1927B3A63C8). The main goal is to avoid back and forth conversions between polynomials as GAP objects and them given by their external representations.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Thanks again, I will change the code today using only the External Representations of Polynomials.
$s$ is the size of the Table Of Marks ( $T$ ) of $G$, so $s$ is the number of conjugacy classes of subgroups of $G$. For each subgroup $U_i$, $\lambda(i,l) := |G/U_i|/|G/U_l|$ and $m_{i,l}$ is obtained by multiplying the $i$th and $l$th row of $T$ entry by entry. This gives you a vector that is then multiplied with $T^{-1}$. The entries of this vector are the $m_{i,l}$.

Comment: $\lambda(i,l) \notin \mathbb Z $ if and only if $m_{i,l}=0$. If $G=S_n$ the polynomial is dense. I'm not sure about the degree yet, but I'll think about it. For now, I'm only interested in the coefficient of some $x^p$ in $\sum_{i=1}^s p_{U_i} $ where $p$ is known before. I'm not interested in the whole polynomial.

Comment: Good! Just keep the old version around as a backup. I will be back in touch later today, will try to organise all remarks in a kind of a proper answer. There is also an idea to calculate only the desired coefficient, skipping the full multiplication of all polynomials.

Comment: I've made some experiments with `ProductCoeffs` - perhaps that could be more efficient than using iterators, please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, that's really an interesting question!

**$0$-th approach**

When multiplying polynomials with integer coefficients, the absolute value of coefficients may increase quite fast. It's important to check that GAP is compiled with [GMP library](https://gmplib.org/) for fast integer arithmetic. You should see `gmp` in the 4-th line of the GAP startup screen:

```
 Libs used:  gmp, readline
```

GMP support was introduced in GAP 4.5 (2012) and is now a default option, so most likely this will be the case.

**Step 1**

The first step is to directly assemble the polynomial from the list of coefficients instead of calculating it as the sum of monomials. In the following example I create a random list `l` of a $1000$ integers between $-10$ and $10$, and then compare these two ways of creating a polynomial with coefficients given by this list:

```
gap> x:=Indeterminate(Rationals,"x");
gap> l:=List([1..10000],i->Random(Integers));;
gap> f:=Sum([1..10000], i-> l[i]*x^i);;time;
2268
gap> f1:=LaurentPolynomialByCoefficients(FamilyObj(1),l,1);;time;
1
gap> f=f1;
true
```

`time` returns the CPU time of the last command in milliseconds, so you see that `LaurentPolynomialByCoefficients` does this instantly, while the other approach takes more than two seconds. See more in "Creation of Rational Functions" from the chapter [Polynomials and Rational Functions](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap66.html) of the GAP reference manual - there are also more low-level functions like `PolynomialByExtRep` and `PolynomialByExtRepNC`, `LaurentPolynomialByExtRep` and `LaurentPolynomialByExtRepNC`, where `NC` stands for "no check" and only should be used if speed is required and the arguments are known to be in correct form. Unless this is guaranteed for the parameters, `LaurentPolynomialByCoefficients` should be used to be on the safe side.

Obviously, there is now no need in `mod` at this step any more, since one could simply truncate the list of coefficients (or not to compute the full list at all).

**Remark:** Step 1 has been verified (see question author's comments above) and reduced in one example the overall runtime from 22 hours to 59 minutes. Steps below are just suggestions, requiring more experimenting and fine-tuning the code.

**Step 2(a)**

Perhaps this could be improved further by using the functionality described in [Arithmetic for External Representations of Polynomials](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap66.html#X809028CD7C0EA7CE) or even [Vectors as coefficients of polynomials](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap23.html#X87FEC1927B3A63C8). The main goal is to avoid back and forth conversions between polynomials as GAP objects and polynomials given by their external representations.

**Added later:** in particular, consider `ProductCoeffs` which allows you to multiply polynomials only partially: `ProductCoeffs( list1[, len1], list2[, len2] )` assumes that  $p1$ (and $p2$) are polynomials given by the first `len1` (`len2`) entries of the coefficient list `list2` (`list2`). If `len1` and `len2` are omitted, they default to the lengths of `list1` and `list2`. Then it returns the coefficient list of the product of $p1$ and $p2$.

If lengths are not restricted, the performance is the same:

```
gap> x:=Indeterminate(Rationals,"x");;
gap> deg:=10000;;
gap> l1:=List([1 .. deg],i->Random(Integers));;
gap> f1:=LaurentPolynomialByCoefficients(FamilyObj(1),l1,0);;
gap> l2:=List([1 .. deg],i->Random(Integers));;
gap> f2:=LaurentPolynomialByCoefficients(FamilyObj(1),l2,0);;
gap> f:=f1*f2;;time;
3819
gap> t:=ProductCoeffs(CoefficientsOfUnivariatePolynomial(f1), CoefficientsOfUnivariatePolynomial(f2));;time;
3787
gap> CoefficientsOfUnivariatePolynomial(f)=t;
true
```

But now assume that we want to calculate coefficient for $x^{10}$ in the product of $p1$ and $p2$. Then we do not have to use monomials of degree 11 and higher. Thus we do:

```
gap> p:=10;
10
gap> tcut:=ProductCoeffs(CoefficientsOfUnivariatePolynomial(f1), p+1, CoefficientsOfUnivariatePolynomial(f2), p+1);;time;
0
gap> CoefficientsOfUnivariatePolynomial(f){[1..p+1]}=tcut{[1..p+1]};
true
```

so we are getting the result instantly, skipping dealing with all monomials of higher degrees. In the same setup, I've got $43$ms for $p=1000$ and $977$ms for $p=5000$, so your mileage may vary, and the smaller $p$ is, the better should be the speedup.

**Step 2(b)**

One could try to experiment with parallelising multiplication of polynomials (given by internal or external representations). The number of polynomials to multiply is the number of conjugacy classes of $G$, e.g. $22$ for $S_8$. The simplest approach would be to split the list of polynomials into chunks and then find a product of each chunk in parallel, and then multiply the resulting products (possibly with another parallel iteration, depending on the number of chunks and nodes). Anyhow, the degree will be rising, and the obvious bottleneck would be the last step with the sequential multiplication of two or three polynomials. If you wish to try to experiment with this, look at the [SCSCP package](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/scscp.html). I could also provide a code for parallel Karatsuba multiplication of polynomials with SCSCP package - for large degree polynomials, it might also speed it up a bit.

**Step 2(c)**

Another speculative suggestion comes from the fact that you may be interested only in a single coefficient. That would be much more helpful if polynomials would be sparse, but still it may be worth to try in the dense case. The idea would be to iterate over the cartesian product of degrees of monomials (using `IteratorOfCartesianProduct`), check for each tuple whether the sum of degrees of monomials is equal to the degree in which you're interested in, and if so then add the product of the respective coefficients to some accumulating variable. The pseudo-code to calculate `p`-th coefficient in GAP could look like

```
degs:= < list of degrees of polynomials >
degranges := List( degs, i -> [1..i] ); # list of ranges 
# for sparse polynomial, take the list of degrees of monomials instead of a range

coeff := 0;

iter:=IteratorOfCartesianProduct(degranges);

for t in iter do
  # t is a tuple of degrees of monomials 
  if Sum(t) = p then
    coeff := coeff + Product( List( [1..Length(t)], i -> 
                              < coefficient for x^t[i] in the i-th polynomial > 
  fi;
od;
```